# Ember.js Ways to Pass Dynamic Segment

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there another way in Ember.js to pass the dynamic segment of a route that's not through the template? The application I'm building uses dynamic segments in, from my understanding, the traditional Ember way where it uses link-to through templates. However, I have a list of records that I'm bringing in and inserting through datatables in a single view. These records each have a link to "edit" them that is manually added as a field within the data. For example, array[0] = record_id, array[1] = some name, array[2] = Edit Record.

```
this.resource('editrecord', { path: 'forms/:form_id/:record_id/editrecord'});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually call a transition to route with `transitionTo(routeName, segmentsValuesObject)` inside of a route:

```
var formId = ...
var recordId = ..
this.transitionTo('editrecord', { form_id: formId, record_id: recordId })
```

or `transitionToRoute(routeName, segmentsValuesObject)` inside of a controller

```
var formId = ...
var recordId = ..
this.transitionToRoute('editrecord', { form_id: formId, record_id: recordId })
```

Each dynamic segment of the route, is represented by key value in `segmentsValuesObject`. Where the key is the name of the dynamic segment, and the value is the current value that will be represented in the url.

Here is a sample with this working http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1316

I hope it helps

Comment: When I try to do that I get the error:

    More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: editrecord

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake. Now the answer is correct. Please give a look

Comment: Thanks Marcio. Your original answer worked well in combination with the serialized topic in Ember.js This is working for the most part but I'm now trying to juggle the right context that is being sent to my helper as the segmentsValuesObject that you discussed no longer holds the model I need to generate a form. However, that's another issue on its own. Thanks again!